# Pandas multiindex not sorted after sort_index method

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

This is the head of my dataFrame

```
            McDonald's  Python  CSS  Microsoft Office        day  week day
Jour                                                                      
2017-06-11          87      22   12                31     Sunday         6
2017-06-12          63      38   24                55     Monday         0
2017-06-13          63      41   25                56    Tuesday         1
2017-06-14          73      41   25                55  Wednesday         2
2017-06-15          72      39   24                53   Thursday         3
```

I did a groupby operation on the dataFrame and I get :

```
df_week = df.groupby(["day", "week day"]).mean()
df_week

                    McDonald's     Python        CSS  Microsoft Office
day       week day                                                    
Friday    4          76.076923  36.615385  22.384615         51.769231
Monday    0          68.230769  37.000000  22.230769         54.230769
Saturday  5          87.416667  21.500000  11.416667         30.750000
Sunday    6          90.000000  21.615385  11.000000         30.538462
Thursday  3          69.923077  40.076923  24.615385         55.846154
Tuesday   1          66.230769  39.461538  24.153846         57.000000
Wednesday 2          68.923077  40.000000  24.846154         56.538462
```

Then I sorted my dataFrame using the weekday index.

```
df_week.sort_index(level="week day", inplace=True)
```

At the end the dataFrame looks like well sorted :

```
                    McDonald's     Python        CSS  Microsoft Office
day       week day                                                    
Monday    0          68.230769  37.000000  22.230769         54.230769
Tuesday   1          66.230769  39.461538  24.153846         57.000000
Wednesday 2          68.923077  40.000000  24.846154         56.538462
Thursday  3          69.923077  40.076923  24.615385         55.846154
Friday    4          76.076923  36.615385  22.384615         51.769231
Saturday  5          87.416667  21.500000  11.416667         30.750000
Sunday    6          90.000000  21.615385  11.000000         30.538462
```

But now, If I try to use the index values, they are still not sorted :

```
print(df_week.index.levels[0])
print(df_week.index.levels[1])

Index(['Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday',
       'Wednesday'],
      dtype='object', name='day')
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64', name='week day')
```

If I look at the whole `MultiIndex` object it is clear that, index label and index lines are store separately.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
           labels=[[1, 5, 6, 4, 0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
           names=['day', 'week day'])
```

Thus, how can I access the index values in the right order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `multiindex levels` is a `frozenlist` is always appears to be sorted and they hold the reference. So if you want the order then convert them to list from frozenlist. i.e  if you use `df.index.tolist()` you can see the real order based of the dataframe. i.e

```
df.index.tolist()

[('Monday', 0),
 ('Tuesday', 1),
 ('Wednesday', 2),
 ('Thursday', 3),
 ('Friday', 4),
 ('Saturday', 5),
 ('Sunday', 6)]
```

Comment: The `tolist()` method does not work if you did it on one specific level. For example : `df_week.index.levels[0].tolist()` returns the unordered list. So you still have to extract the index you need from the list of tuples.